# REF02 not working - 4 channel 5v DAC circuit, star gnd connection, stripboard layout

Tags: arduino, dac, 5v, voltage-reference

I've connected my circuit as in the diagram, with a [15V PSU](https://www.mouser.co.uk/ProductDetail/TDK-Lambda/DSP30-15?qs=m5ogiX%2FX43n0ka1fkZzrNg==) powering it (both amps are connected the same way) - but the DAC seems to be drawing too much current for the REF02 to handle, even though p.24 of the DAC datasheet describes using it in this config. What have I done wrong?

Many thanks for your help

[DAC8555](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/dac8555.pdf)
[REF02](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/REF01_02_03.pdf)
[LM358](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm158-n.pdf)
[image: circuit schematic]
[image: actual layout]

Comment: ... and what do you measure at the pins on the socket where you would plug the REF02 in?

Comment: @brhans One of the stripboard tracks had come apart somehow, but its fixed now. The problem is the REF02 is only giving out 1.45V despite having 15V at Vin?

Comment: I'd break the connection between your REF02 and DAC8555 and then measure the REF02 output to check that the DAC8555 isn't trying to draw too much current. You might need a separate 5V regulator to drive the DAC's Vdd pins.

Comment: @brhans Yes you're right. I've broken the connection and it's giving out 5V. Why is this, as the DAC8555 datasheet below on p.24 specifically describes how to use the REF02 as both a reference and power source? And the only thing its powering is the DAC right, as the opamps are powered by the 15V?

Comment: Seems like something is causing your DAC8555 to draw excessive current. Maybe try disconnecting all of its Vout lines to see if there's an issue with your opamps.

Comment: @brhans I can't find any with the amps, though not sure what I'd be looking for. The problem's solved and it works anyway so they can't be faulty, but only using the arduino power supply. Cheers!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your circuit, you have +15 volts (presumably coming from some type of power supply) connected directly to Vin of the REF02.  You say you measure only 0.35 volts at Vin.  Obviously, something is wrong here. You need to check that the +15 volts is present at the board and then check the wiring to Vin of the REF02 which means both the Vin wiring and the GND wiring. If the REF02 is working outside the board then it is not loading the +15 volts. Something else is going on.

Comment: OK, the problem originally had been the REF02 Vout was only giving 1.45V. Having found one of the stripboard tracks was broke somehow, which I've fixed, its gone back to this. The 15V is now present at Vin, but Vout is only showing 1.45V.

Comment: Try disconnecting Vout from the rest of the circuit.  If the output goes to 5V, then try reconnecting one wire at a time to see which one is loading down the output.  If the output remains at 1.45 V then your REF02 is probably faulty.